# Multiple buttons with an image in HTML

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to add 3 buttons associated with an image.For example, if I have to verify whether an image is good or not, I will have buttons like YES and NO, and the corresponding button is pressed. So far I have an understanding of this sort:

```
<button type="submit">
 <img src="">
 </button>
```

I am not sure as to how I should proceed with an option with 2 buttons or more on a single image.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p><img style="max-height:120px;" src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/3/40451.jpg"/></p>
<p><button>Yes</button> <button>No</button> <button>Maybe</button></p>
```

`<p>` stands for paragraph(new paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><img src="yourImg.jpg" alt="myImage" ></div>
<div><span><button>yes</button></span><span><button>no</button></span><span>
<button>check</button></span></div>
```

or you can use radio button to check whether it is yes or no.Only you have to change ..

```
 yes:<input type="radio"  name="answer"> no:<input type="radio"  
 name="answer">
```